# how to design automated mail format in ruby

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I want to send an automated mail like through SMTP like -
**daily_closing.html.erb**

```
 <p>Dear Sir,</p>

 <p><b>Pending Indents :<%= @pending_indents %></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to    '>>>', "http://www.industryprime.com/notifications/pending_indents" %> </p>

<p><b>Overdue Deliveries :<%= @overdue_delivery %></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to '>>>', "http://www.industryprime.com/notifications/pending_purchase_orders" %></p>
<p><b>Unapproved POs: <%= @unapproved_po_count %></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to '>>>', "http://www.industryprime.com/notifications/po_for_approval" %></p>

<p>Yesterday's GRNs</p>

<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Warehouse</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Make/Catno</th>
  <th>UOM</th>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Closing</th>
  <th></th>      
  </tr>
 </thead>


  <tbody>
  <% @grns.each do |grn| %>
    <tr>

    <td><%= grn.warehouse.description %></td>
    <td><%= grn.date.strftime("%d/%m/%y") %></td>
    <td><%= grn.item.description %></td>

    <% if grn.make_id != nil %>
    <td><%= (grn.make.brand.name)+"/"+(grn.make.catno) %></td>
    <%else %>
    <td></td>
    <% end%>

    <td><%= grn.item.uom.shortform %></td>

    <td><%= grn.quantity.round(2) %></td>

    <td><%= grn.balance_quantity.round(2) %></td>
    <%
    if grn.make_id==nil
    params = {
      :item => grn.item_id,
      :make => 0,
      :date => Time.now,
      :warehouse => grn.warehouse_id
    }
    else  
    params = {
      :item => grn.item_id,
      :make => grn.make_id,
      :date => Time.now,
      :warehouse => grn.warehouse_id
    }
    end
    url = "http://www.industryprime.com/stockledgers?#{params.to_query}"
    %>

    <td><%= link_to '>>>', url %></td>

     </tr>
    <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>


 <p>Yesterday's ISSUEs</p>

 <table border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
  <th>Warehouse</th>
 <th>Date</th>
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Make/Catno</th>
  <th>UOM</th>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Closing</th>
  <th>To</th>
 <th>Cost Centre</th>      
 <th>CF</th>
 <th></th>
</tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
<% @issues.each do |issue| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= issue.warehouse.description %></td>
    <td><%= issue.date.strftime("%d/%m/%y") %></td>
    <td><%= issue.item.description %></td>


    <% if issue.make_id != nil %>
    <td><%= (issue.make.brand.name)+"/"+(issue.make.catno) %></td>
    <%else %>
    <td></td>
    <% end%>

    <td><%= issue.item.uom.shortform %></td>

    <td><%= issue.quantity.round(2) %></td>

    <td><%= issue.balance_quantity.round(2) %></td>

    <td><%= Issue.find(issue.ref_id).parentissue.worker.name %></td>

    <% group = Costcentre.find(Issue.find(issue.ref_id).costcentre_id)
    @leafgroup=Issue.find(issue.ref_id).costcentre.description
    if group.predecessor !=nil
      @pre=-1
      @leafgroup=""
      @group=group
      until  @pre==0 do
        @leafgroup="." + @group.description+@leafgroup 
        if @pre!=nil
          @group=Costcentre.find_by_id(@group.predecessor)
          if@group==nil
            @pre=0
          else
            @pre=@group.predecessor
          end
        else
          @pre=0
        end
      end
      @leafgroup[0]=""
    end
      %>


    <td><%= @leafgroup %></td>
    <td><%= Issue.find(issue.ref_id).costcentre_frequency %></td>
    <%
    if issue.make_id==nil
    params = {
      :item => issue.item_id,
      :make => 0,
      :date => Time.now,
      :warehouse => issue.warehouse_id
    }
    else  
    params = {
      :item => issue.item_id,
      :make => issue.make_id,
      :date => Time.now,
      :warehouse => issue.warehouse_id
    }
    end
    url = "http://www.industryprime.com/stockledgers?#{params.to_query}"
    %>

    <td><%= link_to '>>>', url %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
 </tbody>
  </table>

 <p>Warm regards,</p>
```

when i send this contents in mail its shows- 
[image]

But I want to design with some css color..i.e,row bgcolor..and some othercolor..that not supported in mail contents..
what should i do?

Comment: You need to add the relevant stylesheet or styles to your mailer layout

Comment: Yes, define your css in the head of the html of the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add inline CSS, but it can be tedious and hard job for each element. You can style your mailer by including external stylesheet in your script. What I'm using in my project is [roadie-rails](https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails) gem. When you install roadie-rails gem, it will come with two primary means of usage: "Automatic" and "Manual" you can start with automatic by including automatic module to your mailer ( see [documentation](https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails#automatic-usage) ) :

```
include Roadie::Rails::Automatic
```

In stylesheet folder add for example **mailer.css** and add some classes for your table.

Then you can insert **mailer.css** in layout **app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/mailer.css">   
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you are ready for production go to **config/initializers/assets.rb** and add this line of code to precompile your **mailer.css**:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mailer.css )
```

**Below are steps to make it work in local dev with email preview:**

```
# Generate mailer
rails g mailer newsletter_mailer daily
```

Install 2 gems:

```
   gem 'roadie-rails'   

   # Preview email in the default browser instead of sending it
   group :development do
    gem 'letter_opener' 
   end
```

In **config/environments/development.rb** add this code below, so that you can preview email in your browser instead of sending:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

Code for our mailer **app/mailers/newsletter_mailer.rb**:

```
class NewsletterMailer < ApplicationMailer

  include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

  def daily(email)
    mail(to: email, subject: "Welcome to our website!")
  end
end
```

Create **mailer.css** in a**pp/assets/stylesheets** folder and add for example some styling:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    text-align: center;
}

.email-table {
    width: 538px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 40px auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Now add classes to our **app/views/newsletter_mailer/daily.html.erb** file:

```
<h1>Newsletter#daily</h1>

<table class="email-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header-row">
      <td>
        <h1>Welcome User!</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
      <td>
        <p>Thanks for your registering! We appreciate your interest.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Include external stylesheet in layout  **app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/mailer.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Final step fire up console and send email: `rails c`

```
NewsletterMailer.daily("example@example.com").deliver
```

It will open up new browser window with styled email.

I hope it helps

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear it worked 4 u. Cheers!

Comment: hi sir there is a problem of css style........letter opener worked fine but i cant style with out inline css.....can u help me as soon as possible...

Comment: its partially work.....css class not work in different file. should keep in same file.

Comment: I'm trying to understand you. Do you still have problem?

Comment: is there any issue to include roadie gem  in Action Mailer  instead of Newsletter Mailer?

Comment: I didn't have any issue using roadie gem. Please check these articles, in case that you are using different versions of roadie:   (https://www.cookieshq.co.uk/posts/upgrading-roadie-for-email-styling) 
  (https://www.cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-style-emails-with-rails-and-roadie)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add inline css to that email like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>My Mailer</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body, td { color:#000000; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial; }
      #footer { font-size:11px; color:#555555; }
      #footer a { color:#555555;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    // Your content here
  </body>
</html>
```

To make it easier, you can also use a gem, like [this](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails) one.

Answer (score 0):

Premailer Rails is quite useful to make your mailer decorative!

Add following line to your `Gemfile`

`gem 'premailer-rails'`

Read the full documentation including the configuration [here](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails#introduction). It works exactly similar to the regular html. You just need to include the `css` files explicitly using `stylesheet_link_tag` or simply `<link>` tag.